# Tenant responsibility for smoke detector

Tags: tenant, nevada

Can I replace a broken hardwired smoke detector by myself, or does it need to be done by a certified repairman/electrician to rid myself of liability if something goes wrong?
I live in Nevada.

Bonus: can I replace an old hardwired smoke detector with a battery only one?

Comment: What does your lease say about repairs done by tenants?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch the lease does not specify anything about repairs done by tenants. It only specifies that I need to change the battery. I asked the owner and he seemed OK with it, but I'd like more reassurance.

Answer (score 1):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

All electrical wiring must be by a licensed electrician. If it plugs in, anyone can do it, if you need a screwdriver it has to be an electrician.

All domestic smoke detectors must be hard wired with battery backup and, if there’s more than one in a home they must be interconnected so if one goes off they all go off.